# How do you add a static subpage for Ghost authors?

Tags: ghost-blog

How do I edit the default Ghost routes.yaml file to create a static subpage for each author?

For example, site.com/author/{slug}/static-page. I need to be able to access the specific author's information on the static page, so I am hoping the url points to a custom template such as author-static-page.hbs where I can load the `{{#author}}` information.

This is the default:

```
collections:
  /:
    permalink: /{slug}/
    template: index

taxonomies:
  tag: /tag/{slug}/
  author: /author/{slug}/
```

Comment: Each author already has different page that you can customize, check default theme: https://github.com/TryGhost/Casper/blob/main/author.hbs